# Division of columns not returning proper value

Tags: pandas

I am running into a strange issue where I am trying to divide two columns and despite the expected outcome to be a fraction, it is returning whole values. Is there something that I should be aware of in regard to data types or using division in Pandas that is resulting in this incorret outcome? All columns datatypes are `float64`.

Here is an example of values in one row of the series:

**Correct**

- `installs_mmp` = 19
- `intalls_publisher` = 41
- `installs_mmp_multiplier` = 24.7 (installs_mmp * 1.30)
- `lat_ratio_pub_diff` = 16.3 (installs_publisher - installs_mmp_multiplier)
- `lat_ratio` = 0.39 (lat_ratio_pub_diff / installs_publisher)

Currently the `lat_ratio` is showing **33**, which I can't seem to understand.

Here is my code:

```
df_agg['installs_mmp_multiplier'] = df_agg['installs_mmp'] * 1.30 # 24.7
df_agg['lat_ratio_pub_diff'] = (df_agg['installs_publisher'] - df_agg['installs_mmp_multiplier']) # 16.3
df_agg['lat_ratio'] = df_agg['lat_ratio_pub_diff'] / df_agg['installs_publisher'] # 33
```

Comment: how can dividing a pandas series by a pandas series equal a float? or is that the result of a single row in your series?

Comment: @khuynh that is a single row in the series that I wanted to use to narrow the scope of the issue. I just updated the question to make it clearer

Comment: hmm, i'm not able to reproduce your behavior. can you verify that the data in your series are what you expect them to be? this is the snippet i used: https://replit.com/@hkennyv/AttentiveFittingWireframes#main.py